# ios uiview uiimageview uitextview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uitextview

I have a main UIView that has an UIImageView on it, and the UIView adds an UITextView as a subview. UITextView's frame is smaller than UIView. UIImageView is actually a frame and the rest of the image is transparent and fits the full size of the UIView, but the UITextView is always upon UIView. What I want to achieve is UITextView shows UIView in foreground, while it is possible to scroll up and down on UITextView.

What is the proper way to make it possible?

---

My current code that does not work:

in `loadView`:

```
self.contentview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
self.contentview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ChristmasFrame.png"]]; 
self.contentview.opaque = NO;
self.contentview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self setView:self.contentview];
```

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.contentview addSubview:self.textview];
[self.contentview sendSubviewToBack: self.textview];
```

I want UITextView to be behind self.contentview, so it could show its background image upon the UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

try setting `setUserInteractionEnabled:` to `NO` on `UIView` what is on top of `UITextView`

if that not working you could try to override `hitTest:withEvent:`

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer is unclear. I tried your method with disabling userinteractionenabled.

Comment: `[self.contentview addSubview:self.textview];` it cant be behind - you adding it inside...

Answer (score 0):

make clear color as textview's background color.
and add text view above UIView